# Secondary keyboard shortcuts in Gnome

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

Is there a way to set a secondary keyboard shortcut for a certain action (say, "Volume up")?

Comment: Can you specify version of Ubuntu and type of session (unity, gnome-shell, gnome classic/fallback)?

Comment: Using Gnome 3 fallback, but I guess other people would find useful other variants as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool). Just create a new shortcut with the command
`xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioRaiseVolume` to raise or
`xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioLowerVolume` to lower.

**Step by step instructions:**
1) Install [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool).
2) Open the shortcut manager (on 11.10 and later: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gnome-control-center keyboard`)
3) Choose the tab "Shortcuts"
4) Choose "Custom Shortcuts"
5) Click on "+" like in this picture:

[image]

6) At "Name:" paste `vol`.
7) At "Command:" paste `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioLowerVolume`:

[image]

8) Close the dialog.
9) Click at "Disabled" and make your shortcut.

[image]

10) Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this workaround works. Does this mean there is no support for secondary combinations in Gnome? BTW, funny thing, there is no notification sound when changing volume using this method (and using standard volume keys result causes it).

Comment: That is funny because I got the notification. I don't know for sure (because I'm often surprised by someone), but I couldn't find any support for secondary combinations in Gnome. Best regards.